# Why can't observe document.write on document.body using MutationObserver API?

Tags: javascript, document.write, mutation-observers

I failed to observe `document.write` on `document.body`. Here is code:

```
<script>
var observeDOM = (function(){
    var MutationObserver = window.MutationObserver || window.WebKitMutationObserver,
        eventListenerSupported = window.addEventListener;

    return function(obj, callback){
        if( MutationObserver ){
            // define a new observer
            var obs = new MutationObserver(function(mutations, observer){
                if( mutations[0].addedNodes.length || mutations[0].removedNodes.length )
                    callback();
            });
            // have the observer observe foo for changes in children
            obs.observe( obj, { childList:true, subtree:true });
        }
        else if( eventListenerSupported ){
            obj.addEventListener('DOMNodeInserted', callback, false);
            obj.addEventListener('DOMNodeRemoved', callback, false);
        }
    }
})();

window.onload = function() {
    //console.log("dom ready");

    // Observe a specific DOM element:
    observeDOM( document.body ,function(){ 
        console.log('dom changed');
    });
}

function reload() {
    document.write("<input type=\"submit\" onclick=\"reload();\" value=\"Reload\" />");

    //var text = document.createTextNode("abc");
    //document.body.appendChild(text);
}
</script>
<body>
<input type="submit" onclick="reload();" value="Reload" />
</body>
```

When I click `Reload` button, nothing logged. But if I change code in `window.onload` to:

```
observeDOM( document ,function(){ // change first parameter to *document*
    console.log('dom changed');
});
```

And then click `Reload`, console outputs `dom changed`. Could anyone tell why? I'm using Chrome v50.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the reason today. It seems that `document.write()` covers old `document.body` with a new one. Since MutationObserver was attached to old `document.body`, it can't observe DOM change on new `body`.

Here is how I tested it:

[image]